# Add Button to ToastBar Component

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to add a component, like Button to a ToastBar? I want to add an action button that loads a new form when its clicked. Or is there any method exposed to add listeners to a ToastBar component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure use something like:

```
tb.addMaterialCommandToRightSideMenu("", FontImage.MATERIAL_OPEN_WITH, e -> {
    // button click event
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add an actual button to ToastBar at the moment but you can add an action event.

```
// 10 seconds on screen
ToastBar.showMessage("I am a toast message", FontImage.MATERIAL_OPEN_WITH, 10000, e -> {
    // ToastBar clicked, go to next form
});
```